# VBA Error 429 with Google Earth Pro

Tags: vba, excel, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, activexobject

I have a macro to map data in Google Earth written by a coworker who can run it with no issue.  When I run it, it freezes on:

```
Set GEI = CreateObject("GoogleEarth.ApplicationGE")
```

and throws up Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.  (None of the code above this would pertain to the problem, but I can post if needed.)

We thought it must be a reference library issue from searching, but we both have the same reference libraries checked:
 - Visual Basic For Applications
 - Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
 - OLE Automation
 - Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library

I also tracked down and checked Earth 1.0 Type Library but the same error occurred.

From searching, I have not been able to figure out what file or where to get it.  Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: `CreateObject` is a late bound call, so you shouldn't expect to find it in your references.  Is the .dll registered?

Comment: Thanks...  I am not sure how to check if the .dll is registered, or even what .dll it needs to work.

Comment: Open up regedit.exe and search for "GoogleEarth.ApplicationGE". If it isn't there, that's the issue - I'm not familiar with the library, so I'm not sure what .dll you'd need to register. You can do a registry search on a machine it works on to find it.  There should be a key somewhere for InprocServer32 that has the .dll path for the ActiveX server.